# Windows 2008 Scheduled Tasks and Parallel instance issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, command-line-interface, scheduled-task

I have a scheduled task launching a bat file which runs a CLI PHP script.

The scheduled task is configured to run every 5 minutes, and run multiple instances in parallel.

However, windows is launching up to 7 of these tasks at one scheduled run, which is incorrect. It needs to only run one every 5 minutes, and allow multiple instances to run in parallel if any previous running task is still running.

Does anyone know how we can fix this issue? Seems windows is doing an invalid check or something.